# Parsing this sentence containing a "when" clause

Tags: subjects, adverbial-phrases

Consider:

> A premium of 0.2 per cent is to be added to the CIRRs when fixing at bid. Interest rates may not be fixed for longer than 120 days.

([Source](http://www.oecd.org/trade/xcred/cirrs.pdf))

Why can "a premium" act as the subject for "fixing at bid" in this "when" clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You correctly discern a violation of formal grammar here. Formally, the omitted subject of the subordinate clause should be referable to the subject of the matrix clause; and as you observe, it would be nonsensical to suggest that the *premium* fixes.

However, it is a very minor violation, of a sort you will encounter frequently in commercial English. Everybody in the industry knows what *fixing at bid* means, so there is no ambiguity here. In fact, the matter arises precisely because *fixing at bid* has a sort of independent existence as a shorthand gerund phrase, and it happens to be difficult to fit that phrase gracefully into a *when* clause. I suggest you parse the sentence as if there has been a deletion of either the subject or the verb in the subordinate clause:

> ..., when the parties fix at bid.
>    ..., when fixing at bid occurs.

Comment: Thx for your consistent help! And I wonder if bid here stands for a formal occasion for bid.

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng I'm not familiar with currency transactions; in the markets I'm familiar with *bid* means either "a price offered" or "the action of offering a price". My **guess** is that *at bid* here means something like *on the occasion of offering* or *as a component of an offer*.

Answer (score 1):

"A premium" means "an extra" in this context. So this sentence basically means "Whatever the rate is usually, it will be 0.2% extra".

Comment: thx, i know what premium means, but i just wonder what acts as the subject for "fixing at bid" here. Obviously premium cannot be the omitted subject for this when clause. i think it is grammatically wrong here.